# How to create the copies of elements of array?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have one string array in Java like

```
  String arr[] = {"A", "B" , "C", "D"};
```

Now what I am trying to do is that taking any int number from user like e.g 8 and I have to print the letter corresponding to that number.
But the twist is that every time when arr[] completes like "A"=1, "B"=2 , "C"=3, "D"=4, then after that it create the copies of each element in an array like e.g and start counting from there

```
  arr[] = {"A","A", "B","B", "C","C", "D","D"}
```

so according to that now the value of number  "A"=5 , "A"=6, "B"=7, "B"=8.

So the answer it should print "B".

Similarly the value of number can by anything and accordingly it has to create the array and find the value.

Comment: Rajaprabhu @Now I am still thinking and not able to get any efficient or good way to do same.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for what you're trying to do is HashMap. 
Adding entries to an normal array in java is impossible, because their size can't be changed. HashMap offers extendability and the possibility to have a reference to an index (eg : "potato"="First-class", "strawberry"="Second-class"), etc.
A little overview of HashMaps : http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to actually duplicate the elements, you just need to keep track of how many times you would be duplicating the elements. This is an efficient way of doing it:

```
public static String selectString(String[] arr, int n) {
    //n--; Add this line if you want n=1 to be the first element, rather than n=0
    int size = arr.length;
    int duplicate = 1;

    while(n >= size) {
        n -= size;
        size *= 2;
        duplicate *= 2;
    }

    return arr[n/duplicate];
}
```

Here's the output of the first 13:

```
0:A 1:B 2:C 3:D 4:A 5:A 6:B 7:B 8:C 9:C 10:D 11:D 12:A
```